# Why does my constructor not initialize its superclass attributes like it should?

Tags: c++, inheritance

See, i have a Cat.

```
#pragma once
#include "../CoreComponents/MTT_GraphicalStaticObject.h"


class Cat : public MTT_GraphicalStaticObject {
public:
    Cat(int x, int y) : MTT_GraphicalStaticObject(x, y) {};
    Cat(int* x, int* y) : MTT_GraphicalStaticObject(x, y) {};

};
```

The Cat is derived from my custom class called MTT_GraphicalStaticObject :

```
#pragma once
#include "MTT_GraphicalObject.h"

class MTT_GraphicalStaticObject: public MTT_GraphicalObject {
public:

    MTT_GraphicalStaticObject() :MTT_GraphicalObject() {};
    MTT_GraphicalStaticObject(int x, int y) :MTT_GraphicalObject(x, y) {  };
    MTT_GraphicalStaticObject(int* x, int* y) : MTT_GraphicalObject(x, y) {};

    int* x = NULL; 
    int* y = NULL;

    void loadSpriteFromFilename(std::string filename);
    void render(Camera cam);


protected:
    MTT_Texture spriteTexture;
};
```

...and MTT_GraphicalStaticObject is derived from an abstract class that you can see here.

```
#pragma once
#include "MTT_Texture.h"
#include <string>
#include "../Graph/Camera.h"


class MTT_GraphicalObject {

public:

    MTT_GraphicalObject();
    MTT_GraphicalObject(int x, int y);
    MTT_GraphicalObject(int* x, int* y);

    int* x = NULL; 
    int* y = NULL;
    virtual void render(Camera cam) = 0;

};
```

**But.**

Something is wrong when i try to play with my cat.
See below:

```
int* in = new int(40);
Cat* cat = new Cat(in,in);
cat->loadSpriteFromFilename("Cat.png");
overworldGraphicalManager->aRandomCat = cat; 
; //My breakpoint here says that my cat x and y value are not initialized.
```

The same occurs when i try to do this :

```
Cat* cat = new Cat(40,40);
cat->loadSpriteFromFilename("Cat.png");
overworldGraphicalManager->aRandomCat = cat; 
; //same result
```

It however **works** if i do this :

```
int* in = new int(40);
Cat* cat = new Cat(in,in);
cat->x = in;
cat->y = in;
cat->loadSpriteFromFilename("Cat.png");
overworldGraphicalManager->aRandomCat = cat;
; //It works! But i don't want these kind of workarounds.
```

My question is simple : **Why such a thing occurs?**

Answering it will help me to find a solution in order to be able to initialize my cat in a socially acceptable maneer.

(here is the source code for the initializers)

```
#include "../../Headers/CoreComponents/MTT_GraphicalObject.h"

MTT_GraphicalObject::MTT_GraphicalObject() {
    this->x = 0;
    this->y = 0;
}

MTT_GraphicalObject::MTT_GraphicalObject(int x, int y)
{
    this->x = &x;
    this->y = &y;
}

MTT_GraphicalObject::MTT_GraphicalObject(int* x, int* y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

Comment: `GraphicalObject(int x, int y)` - inside this constructor, x and y are local variables. Storing their address is a Bad Idea(tm)

Comment: `int* in = new int(40);`? Why? What is the reason you even have constructors accepting pointers? It makes no sense.

Comment: Also, `MTT_GraphicalStaticObject::x` and `MTT_GraphicalObject::x`, why the variable duplication? The same with `y`. In fact `MTT_GraphicalStaticObject::x` will *hide* `MTT_GraphicalObject::x`.

Comment: I think you're misconcepting the pointers in the initialization.

Comment: (I'm still fairly new with pointers and stuff, (and c++ in general...) and even if i understand the concept i still struggle a bit with the semantics. I apologize.)

Comment: Also, always prefer smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: For what you show, there's no need for `x` and `y` to be pointers at all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i think that i need them to be pointers because all of this code is from a prototype for a videogame i am working on, with two managers (a graphical one and a logical one) who need to interact with the values. I omitted this detail considering the fact that i only want to understand how the initializer works in this case.
Thank you for the variable duplication advice. There is a lot of trial and error in this little project.

Comment: I still don't see the need for `x` and `y` to be pointers. If you need to get their values then add getter functions to the `MTT_GraphicalObject` class. And if you need to set them as well then perhaps make them `public` (or rethink your design)? Outside of polymorphism, there's rarely a need to use pointers these days. And pointers to single primitive values (or containers) almost never.

Comment: More to the point, if these are pointers because their values are shared by other things at the callsite, then at the very least you need to be passing pointers to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take addresses of local variables:

```
MTT_GraphicalObject::MTT_GraphicalObject(int x, int y)
{
    this->x = &x;
    this->y = &y;
}
```

The address points onto stack. After leaving the scope it disappears, so you have unpredictable behavior.

From you case I don't think you need ever declare class members as pointers.

```
int* x = NULL; 
int* y = NULL;
```

Review use `int x, y` as values

Comment: I thought that pointers were helping me in my case, but after modifying the code to adapt to the use of "classic" values instead, it appears it is much more simple without them. The fact that i mainly use c++ to fiddle around with the SDL (which is written in C, and hence use pointers to some extent) made me think that they were cool and all, but let's not take a rocket launcher to splat a fly : i won't use them unless it's necessary from now on. Thank you!